# Как посмотреть параметры сборки PHP?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, debian

`php -i` почему то не выводит информацию о Configure Command.

Answer (score 2):

Установите `php5-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Потом запустите команду.

```
php-config  --configure-options
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать и открыть файл в браузере содержащий команду php_info(); Данная функция выводит полную информацию об установленом PHP